# Android - Control Overlay question

Tags: android, controls

I'm trying to add some control overlays to an activity as such:

```
----------
|overlay |
----------
|        |
|activity|
|        |
----------
| overlay|
----------
```

i want the overlay portions to handle clicks, but i want the center portion to be transparent and have the activity receive touch events and whatnot.

is there a way to specify that a certain region of the layout is clipped?

obviously, i could add each item of the overlay to the underlying activity, in which this wouldn't be an issue, but i'd like to bundle both overlay portions into one control. and add the control as a single item.

is this possible?

Answer (score -2):

An Activity creates a window for you, which contains a view.  You can't embed an activity within anything.  You should read through the [Android fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) if you haven't yet, to get a good understanding of what an Activity and View are.

It sounds like what you want is a header and footer with some content in between.  That is very obtainable, just not how you explained.

If you have a `ListView` in the middle, you can use its [addHeaderView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) and addFooterView functions.

Otherwise, you can use a layout to position things at the top and bottom with a scroll view in the middle.

If your header and footer are complex, and you want to add them to multiple pages you can create each in its own layout and include them in your other layouts.  See [merging layouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html).

Comment: Been through the fundamentals, i understand what an activity and a view are. i'm not trying to embed an activity at all. i'm trying to overlay controls on top of an activity. very different. please re-read the question.

Comment: Well what do you think the overlays are if not another activity?  You can only have one active activity at a time.  So no, you cannot have an activity with other things overlayed and still be able to interact with the the one on the bottom.

Comment: Z-ordered controls. like in every other UI framework in existence.

Comment: Using `RelativeLayout` you can place views (controls) above other views.

Comment: Really?  Every UI framework in existence allows you to have an Activity with other controls overlayed?  Regardless, mobile development is a different paradigm than desktop development.  As suggested, you are best off overlaying views within an Activity.  It has the same effect as what you want.

Comment: Andrey, thanks, we've done that. In our control constructor we pass a reference to the activity and then add the views to that activity. However, what i would really like is to make a single view from the control that overlays the entire thing, but has a masked area in the middle in which the touches are passed through to the underlying views.

Comment: Mayra, you should just stop commenting, your answers are just polluting the discussion.